# How to pass Textfield conroller into Button Picker flutter widget

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build an app that uses flutter button picker widget as a way of collecting data. However, it does not have a controller property to uniquely identify each number picker widget. Can any one assist me?

Here is the link to the flutter button Picker widget:

https://pub.dev/packages/button_picker

Comment: Your question is not very easy to understand. Please share your code to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want this widget to have a contoller property that can be used to save a form:

Comment: ButtonPicker(controller: myController   )

Comment: You haven't shared your code and you haven't read the guidelines. It's unlikely that anyone will answer your question if you don't improve it.

Comment: I want to pass a controller into this widget to make the number picked saved into a database:

Comment: ButtonPicker(
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 99,
            initialValue: 0,
            onChanged: (val) => print(val),
            step: 2.5,
            horizontal: false,
            loop: true,
            padding: 5.0,
            iconUp: Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
            iconDown: Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
            iconLeft: Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
            iconRight: Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
            iconUpRightColor: Colors.blue,
            iconDownLeftColor: Colors.blue,
            )